# Inserting many objects in Bash script

Tags: bash, multiple-insert

I am trying to use multiple inputs at the same files in a command as an output, from this question I made

[looping object as inputs in BASH, SHELL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572871/looping-object-as-inputs-in-bash-shell-script/24573250?noredirect=1#comment38064340_24573250)

The user Konsolebox and all the others were very helpful in giving me to understand how the process may be improved and operate.
After their suggestion I took their inputs and tried to alter my code, although it does not seem to work.

The code's job is to take multiple items with difference in time and/or months and input them as input files to a bash command which will produce one single output file

The suggestions proposed made me alter the code this way:

```
fname2="trim"
years=({2000..2010})
months=(01 02)  ## ({01..100}) should be the same
end="nc"
```

I have been trying to make it work but no matter what i change i get the same error

```
cdo mergetime: Open failed on >@({2010})@(01<
No such file or directory
```

I have placed the bash script in the working folder and the files are named `trim201001.nc` and `trim201002.nc` (usually i will have hundreds with that format that is why i am trying to automatize them)

I am running the script with the command `./script.sh`

after the advice of konsolebox i added `shopt -s nullglob`

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nullglob
#IFS='|' eval 'pattern="${fname2}@(${years[*]})@(${months[*]}).${end}"'
IFS='|' eval 'pattern="${fname2}$years@(${months[*]}).${end}"'

echo "pattern = ${pattern}"
files=($pattern)  ## pathname expansion is sorted in Bash.

cdo mergetime "${files[@]}" ofile
```

And the new error i think is located in the month reading, although i checked my location the one file that is to be use is 02 (month) and 01 (month)

```
pattern = @(2010)@(01|02).nc

cdo mergetime: Open failed on >02).nc<
No such file or directory
```

Comment: What does `echo "$pattern"` say if you insert it after the second command? And it should have been a good thing that you have added `shopt -s nullglob` (I should have suggested that sorry).

Comment: And make sure you run your script with bash e.g. `bash script.sh` not `sh script.sh`

Comment: I also noticed: `years=({2000...2010})` has 3 dots. It should only be two: `years=({2000..2010})`

Comment: @konsolebox Whereshould i add the  shopt -s nullglob? i changed the years = ({2010}), although it still  but the error is the same.

Comment: You can add it after `shopt -s extglob`. That should be valid with bash. Are you running your script with `bash your_script.sh`? What version of bash do you have? See `bash --version`.

Comment: Adding `nullglob` means that no value would be given even if no match is found. By default a pattern yields itself if a file is not found on it. e.g. `echo *` would print `*` if no file exists. Probably you can also test your command with `[[ ${#files[@]} -gt 0 ]] && cdo mergetime ...` which would only execute the command if files are found.

Comment: @konsolebox I am using GNU bash 4.1.2, and i run my file in this manner ./script.sh

Comment: Does it make any difference if you run it with `bash script.sh`? Is the header set as `#!/bin/bash` and not `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: @konsolebox #!/bin/sh i have other scripts with that and it works

Comment: Well perhaps the other scripts don't need functions that are specific to Bash. Many of the functions on the example solution I proposed were bash-specific.

Comment: @konsolebox I use bash just as a black box to be honest, the scripts i am writing often times are called to execute other toolboxes. I added the command you told me and the error now has been limited to the month, please see the question above i have inserted the new error.

Comment: Having only one argument in `{}` is no longer a form of brace expansion. You need to have two i.e. `{A..B}`. See [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html). If you only want to give one element to your array, just do `years=(2010)`. And I actually wonder why you don't get the proper pattern for months. It should be `@(01|02)`.

Comment: I'm sorry. The declaration to `IFS` has a typo. It should be `IFS='|'` not `ISF='|'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57081/discussion-between-george-and-konsolebox).